# Sometimes when I print to command line, my code stops running until I press control+c

Tags: terminal, printf

For example, when I print from a loop, lets say something like:

```
for i in range(0,10):
    print(i)
```

it wont print me all of the digits - sometimes, it will just completely half until i press control+c, in which it will continue. Not sure what could be causing this.

Using Python, Command Prompt

Comment: Which terminal are you using? What language is this?

Comment: Help us understand a bit more how you run this. You have these 2 lines in a python file named `something.py`. Add one more line after `print(i)`. Type `print('Done')`. Ensure that this last print is not indented. It should be in the same column as `for`. Go to command line and type `python3 something.py`. What do you see? Take a screenshot and put it in your question.